# Is there a more efficient way to loop through this sql result set?

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a table in a database filled with categories structured like this:

pk int: cat_id
int: parent_id
varchar: cat_name

A top level category has a null parent_id and there could be several levels of children.
Basically, I am taking a search string and matching it against the category names, and if the category has parents then I want to display the full path in breadcrumb fashion for all matches. Here is pseudo code for what I am doing now:

```
search_string = whatever;
result = query db and find all category names matching "%whatever%";
foreach(result)
{
    parent_id = result[parent_id];
    result_path = result[cat_name];
    while(parent_id != null)
    {
        result2 = query db and find cat_id = parent_id;
        result_path = result2[cat_name] + " > " + result[path];
        parent_id = result2[parent_id];
    }
    print result_path;
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this other than the nested loop and database queries?

Thanks for any input.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL) in general, any nested query that is based on results from the parent query can/SHOULD be rewritten as a join.

Comment: I tried joining the table on itself, can you give me an example of how this n-level join could be written?

Comment: @user2027914: how big is your table with categories? If around hundred(s) - how about fetching everything as `select * from category` and building the tree on php side?

Comment: Instead of querying db for each parent_id, you can get the list of parent ids from results and use `cat_id IN (parent_ids)` to reduce the number of database calls.  For each result you iterate in php and use them as you want.

Comment: @zerkms: I certainly could fetch everything and build a tree and traverse it in the server side code, if I stick with this table structure that may be one of the best ways to eliminate the numerous nested db calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have is a hierarchy stored as an adjacency list. Recursion is the only practical way to solve this, either in MySql or PHP.

If you are seriously looking for efficiencies for this particular query then store your hierarchy as nested sets. Be aware that this is a non-trivial exercise and will increase the cost of maintaining your data. It will also reduce the efficiency of other queries such as finding children.

There is plenty of info on this site and others about storing hierarchical data in RDMS.

Comment: "If you are seriously looking for efficiencies then store your hierarchy as nested sets" --- that's not true. "The adjacency list is rarely the best method." --- that's not true as well.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Adjacency lists vs. nested sets seems to be exactly what I need to be looking at here. I found this link to be a very helpful comparison of the two: [Manage Hierarchical Data In MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)